Forgot password from Firebase always reports success
I am making a web application in angular. I connected the login with firebase. I want to implement password reset functionality. By entering the email and clicking on the "forgot password" button, the email is successfully sent. The problem is that if I enter an email that is not in the database, the next block is always executed instead of an error, that is, it always says that the email was sent successfully. What do I need to change so that the error block is executed in case of entering an email that does not exist in the database?
signin.component.ts
  forgotPassword() {
    this.isRecoveringPassword = true;

    this.authenticationService.forgotPassword(this.form.value.email).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        this.isRecoveringPassword = false;
        this.snackBar.open(
          'Password reset email has been sent to your email account.',
          'OK',
          {
            duration: 5000,
          }
        );
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
        this.isRecoveringPassword = false;
        this.snackBar.open(error.message, 'OK', {
          duration: 5000,
        });
      },
    });
  }

authentication.service.ts
forgotPassword(email: string): Observable<void> {
    return from(this.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email));
  }

signin.component.html
 <button
          mat-button
          [disabled]="!form.get('email')!.valid"
          (click)="forgotPassword()"
          *ngIf="!isRecoveringPassword"
          test-id="forgot-password-button"
        >
          Forgot your password?
        </button>


This is the expected behavior on projects created since September 15, 2023. On these newer projects Firebase has auto-enabled its protection against email enumeration attacks, and the way you expect the API to work would enable such an attack. That's why this API now always returns
For more on this, see the documentation on email enumeration protection. From there:

[This change] Removes error responses for email verification flows, such as those initiated by calling the sendOobCode REST API with request types VERIFY_AND_CHANGE_EMAIL or PASSWORD_RESET, and when calling verifyBeforeUpdateEmail for Web and Android, sendEmailVerification(beforeUpdatingEmail:) for iOS, or sendPasswordResetEmail client SDK methods on all platforms.

You'll either have to code for the current behavior, or disable the protection (as shown in the docs).
